# Euler's totient function to estimate $\pi$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, pi, totient-function

[Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(n)$ to estimate $\pi$

$$\pi = \sqrt{6 \times \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\varphi(i)}{i} \right)^{-1} \right)}$$

**The Idea**

Started looking at Euler's totient function a few days ago and noticed that on the line $x + y = n$, the number of [points visible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) from the origin equals $\varphi(n)$. Being aware that $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ represents the probability that [two randomly chosen integers are coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#:%7E:text=In%20a%20sense%20that%20can,2b%20%E2%80%93%201%20are%20coprime.), I wondered if there's a connection between $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ and Euler's totient function? Anyhow, after a few hours of thinking, the above formula popped out. To verify it, wrote a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/boWTor1bh) C program and it outputs $\pi \approx 3.141592$.

**Question**

As a programmer (not a maths guy), the program computes $\pi \approx 3.141592$ which looks promising but is the maths behind it legitimate?

Comment: So you just wonder whether this expression is actually $\pi$ ? I ask because it would not be useful to use it in practice. The convergence will be extremely slow and moreover , to determine $\varphi(i)$ , we have to factor $i$.

Comment: The "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything" is $\pi$ (not $42$) as calculated by an enormous supercomputer named Deep Thought over a period of 7.5 million years. Yeah, it's extremely slow. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}\frac{\varphi(i)}{i}$, if it exists, certainly isn't negative. Therefore, your conjecture is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}.
$$
Proving such identities using complex analysis is the purview of analytic number theory. A detailed proof requires a lot of theory I'm guessing you don't know yet, but the short version is: there is a theorem, which says
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)L_{\varphi}(s+1),
$$
where $L_{\varphi}(s)$ is the meromorphic continuation of $s\mapsto \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s}$ to the entire complex plane.

Next, note that for all integers $n\ge 1$, we have $\varphi(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\frac nd$, where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Let $I:\mathbb{Z}_{n\ge 1}\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ be given by $I(n)=1$ for all $n\ge 1$, then we have $\varphi=\mu *I$, where '$*$' denotes [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). Now, subject to some easily checked convergence conditions, we know that $L_{\varphi}(s)=L_\mu(s)L_I(s)=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>2$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Hence,
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac1x\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}=\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s+1)}=\frac1{\zeta(2)}\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)
\zeta(s)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot 1 = \frac{6}{\pi^2},
$$
as desired. Your identity is correct!

If you want to understand how identities like these can be proven, study complex analysis, geared towards Dirichlet series and $L$-functions. Among various interesting results, the famous Prime Number Theorem is also proved using these techniques.